# QString::split(" ") works only for the first element

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a program to sort through a string of items separated by spaces. When I use the first element of listt (listt[0]) the program runs perfectly fine, however when I try anything other then listt[0] like listt[1] or listt[2] I get an error. Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
//text from text file
Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 10 9 10 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 10 7 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 10 10 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Bob Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 8 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Bob Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 8 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 


//relevant part of code using listt[0] (works)
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString line, name;
    int avglist;
    QString *reallist;
    reallist =new QString[10000];
    QString *listof;
    QStringList listt;
    listof =new QString[10000];
    int x=0;

    name=ui->lineEdit->text();

    QFile file("C:/Users/brandan/Desktop/GUIPrograms/Kumonreal.txt");

    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QTextStream stream(&file);

        do
        {
        line = stream.readLine();
        listof[x] = line;
        qDebug() << line;
        x++;
        } while(!line.isNull());
    }

    for (int q=x; q>=0; q--)
    {
        QString Parsing;
        Parsing = listof[q];

        listt = Parsing.split(" ");

        qDebug() << listt[0]; //"name" in string
        reallist[q] = listt[0];


    }

    int Counter = sort(reallist,x,name);
    qDebug() << Counter;

}
```

Comment: "an error" -- what error?  What line?  A compile time error?  A run time error?  Can you, I don't know, share this error with us?

Comment: runtime error when I click my button.

Comment: Please be more specific. What happens in what line?

Comment: If I were to change qDebug() << list[0] to qDebug() << list[1] the program would come up with a runtime error when the button is pushed

Comment: Did you check in your debugger for the contents of `listt`? Did you check in your debugger the contents of `listof` or `Parsing`?

Comment: Yeah it prints out the whole line properly.

Comment: Where? In your second loop, you are only printing the first element. Did you check with your debugger? It's way easier than adding heaps of print statements.

Comment: Yes when I tried to print the second element the program failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails because of two specific bugs. I list them first. Other bugs don't make it immediately fail, but are bugs nevertheless.

1. You're reading empty lines and the result of `split()` then has one element. You're trying to access non-existing elements and it fails.
2. Your second loop starts at an invalid index into `listof` since you've incremented `x` too far. So, you try to access a default-constructed empty string because your `x` is one too large. If you happen to read 10,000 lines, your `x` will point past the end of the array: index 10,000 is invalid, last one is 9,999!
3. You don't deallocate the memory allocated for the elements of the lists. Use smart pointers to help you out with that. You should use `QScopedArrayPointer` for arrays  allocated with `new Type[]`. It is an error (even if it doesn't crash!) to use `QScopedPointer` on such arrays.
4. Any extra spaces at the end of the line, or within the line, will be converted to spurious elements. Pass `QString::SkipEmptyParts` as a second argument to `split`.
5. The code will fail if presented with an empty file. Your check for end of file is wrong, you should use `stream.atEnd()` instead.
6. The code also will fail if the file cannot be opened: You should immediately exit when the file cannot be opened - there's no point to the rest of the code then, and it saves some indentation and makes it easier to read.
7. The code will fail if presented with a file of more than 10,000 elements: You have fixed-size arrays.
8. The code will fail if any line has less than 2 elements in it.

Fixing all of those bugs yields this horrible C++ code. It doesn't crash and burn, it works "correctly" for files with 10,000 entries or less, but it's still **bad code**:

```
void processDataOrg(QIODevice * dev)
{
    if (!dev->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

    const int N = 10000;
    QScopedArrayPointer<QString> listof(new QString[N]);
    QTextStream stream(dev);
    int x = -1; /* FIX for problem #2 */
    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        QString line = stream.readLine();
        listof[++x] = line;  /* FIX for problem #2 */
        if (x == N-1) break;
    }

    QScopedArrayPointer<QString> reallist(new QString[N]);
    for (int q=x; q>=0; q--) {
        QString Parsing = listof[q];
        QStringList listt = Parsing.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        if (listt.size() < 2) continue; /* FIX for problem #1 */

        qDebug() << listt[0] << listt[1];
        reallist[q] = listt[0];
    }
}
```

Of course you wouldn't have those problems if you were using the lists as they were meant to be used! Appending to a list doesn't need you to keep track of any indices. Neither you need to worry about indices when iterating a list. You're coding like if it was C, not C++. Your code could be simplified as below.

```
void processDataBetter(QIODevice * dev)
{
    if (!dev->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

    QStringList lines;
    QTextStream stream(dev);
    while (! stream.atEnd()) {
        lines << stream.readLine();
    }

    QStringList names;
    foreach (QString line, lines) {
        QStringList elements = line.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        if (elements.size() < 2) continue;
        qDebug() << elements[0] << elements[1];
        names << elements[0];
    }
}
```

It still doesn't make any sense to keep the `lines` list, so:

```
void processDataOK(QIODevice * dev)
{
    if (!dev->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

    QStringList names;
    QTextStream stream(dev);
    while (! stream.atEnd()) {
        QString line = stream.readLine();
        QStringList elements = line.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        if (elements.size() < 2) continue;
        qDebug() << elements[0] << elements[1];
        names << elements[0];
    }
}
```

Since you seem to wish to sort the data by name, you can use `QMap` as a data structure that implicitly sorts its entries by key.

For our test, we can use a `QBuffer` instead of a `QFile` to have a self-contained, single-file example. The output is sorted by name:

```
"Bob" "Janurary" 
"Bob" "Janurary" 
"Brandan" "Janurary" 
"Brandan" "Janurary" 
"Brandan" "Janurary"
```

Finally, a reasonably correct, self-contained example:

```cpp
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMultiMap>
#include <QDebug>

QByteArray fileData(
    "Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 10 9 10 9 0 0 0 0 0 0\n"
    "Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 10 7 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0\n"
    "Brandan Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 10 10 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0\n"
    "Bob Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 8 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0\n"
    "Bob Janurary 1 2000 Math 7A 4 9 8 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0");

void processData(QIODevice * dev)
{
    if (! dev->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;

    typedef QMultiMap<QString, QStringList> Map;
    Map map;

    QTextStream stream(dev);
    while(! stream.atEnd()) {
        QString line = stream.readLine().trimmed();
        QStringList elements = line.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
        if (elements.count() < 2) continue;
        QString name = elements[0];
        map.insert(name, elements);
    }

    for (Map::const_iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
        qDebug() << it.key() << it.value()[1];
    }
}

int main()
{
    QBuffer buf(&fileData);
    processData(&buf);
}
```

Comment: With that answer, the question seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com ...

Comment: @user3183586 The map is there because you seem to want to sort your list by name. I'm simply showing how to do it. This is working, tested code. Also, the fixed allocation bugs that you have are not about efficiency, they are about safe coding practices. You basically wrote code that has no chance of ever working correctly.

Comment: Yeah that works and I can actually understand it, thank you very much. And my code is very bad I have to admit i'm still a beginner to object oriented programming and this was my first "independent" program I attempted. I am going to however try and push myself for safe coding practices because i'm sure coding large programs without doing so would be hell.

Comment: @user3183586 C and C++ are very, very different languages. A lot of idioms from C don't really have much use in general-purpose C++ code. Unfortunately, there are many examples out there of C++ code that's very, very bad. Assume that everything from cplusplus.com is bad, because often it is and you're too new to know otherwise.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice, will do. Also I just want to thank you again for  putting so much effort into your answer and explaining it, it was extremely helpful not only in my program but also in my whole out take on coding in general.

Answer (score 1):

the return type of QString::split() is QStringList not QString*

so in your code should like this:

```
QStringList listt = Parsing.split(" ");
```

and access like

```
listt[0]
listt[1]
listt[2]...
```

Comment: I still get an error message using this when I try and use anything other then list[1].

Comment: Also listt was declared at the beginning of the program as a QStringList

Comment: your two loops are very confusing. the last element of listof seems that it always is null.

Comment: Yes but I don't think my loops are the problem.

Comment: base on your code, after first loop, your listof should have 6 elements and last one list[5] is null, and your x should be 6. when the code arrives to second loop, your access list[6] first, which is kind of undefined.

Comment: Ok I understand that however my real problem is with .split because only the first element of listt (not list btw) is working.

Comment: before you access listt[x] make sure your listt size is x+1 at least.

Comment: You dont have to declare the size of listt because its a QStringList. It takes the size of how many elements your string is.

Comment: no, when you want to split listof[q] if this listof[q] is null, your return QStringList has size which is not what you expected. and when you access listt[5] you will get an error, please qDebug() the size of listt before you access it, you will see.

Comment: What should I change the loop too?